# additional function of ko.observablearray like removeall, indexOf comes as not supported

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have two ko.observablearray.
One of the arrays I'm populating with some values I get from the server:

`self.AllItems = ko.observableArray([]);

```
function (data) {
   for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
   self.AllItems.push(data[index]);
   }
 };
```

The second array with data that I get from a particular property of my model.

```
self.SelectedItems = ko.observableArray(modelData.Modalities);
```

This works fine.

Now I essentially want to remove the "selecteditems" from the "allitems".

I tried

```
self.AllItems.removeAll(self.SelectedItems());
```

That didnt work.
And then I was trying `indexOf` when I got an exception which said that the object does not support this operation. I'm thoroughly confused. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A56yp/) to show that your logic is good.

```
var all =ko.observableArray([]);

for(var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    all.push({'name':('item'+index)});
}

var itemsToRemove = ko.observableArray([])
itemsToRemove.push(all()[2]);
itemsToRemove.push(all()[5]);

all.removeAll(itemsToRemove());

console.log(JSON.stringify(all()));
// results : [{"name":"item0"},{"name":"item1"},{"name":"item3"},{"name":"item4"},{"name":"item6"},{"name":"item7"},{"name":"item8"},{"name":"item9"}]
```

Can you check what is in modelData.Modalities ?

Comment: The problem seems to lie elsewhere. My AllItems list contains the values, which I can see because I've bound it to a ui control, shows the length as zero. Am not able to access any of the elements in it.

Comment: Are you sure that you should not use modelData.Modalities() instead of modelData.Modalities ?

Comment: Yes that works fine. I also verified the contents of the selectedItems array.

Comment: So you need create a fiddle with the problem.